# I can't change the position of my FPSController

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, position

I created a simple shooter in Unity and i want to change the position of my Player (FPSController). I can only change the position when i do it in the Prefab but this is useless for me.
If i call functions like "InstantiatePlayer()" where it tries to change the position, the player will be teleported after 0.1 sec back to the old position.

```
public void InstantiatePlayer()
{
    GameObject temp = Instantiate(PlayingplayerPref);
    temp.transform.position = new Vector3(31, 6, 7);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

vgro's solution is ok, but instead of creating a new Quaternion you should use Quaternion.identity, won't do much of a difference here but it's good practice

Answer (score 0):

You can specify the position when on instantiating.

```
Instantiate(Object PlayingplayerPref, Vector3 position, Quaternion rotation);
```

If you dont want to specify the rotation just set the quaternion to (0,0,0,0), so you will have

```
Instantiate(PlayingplayerPref, position, new Quaternion(0,0,0,0);
```

Hope this helps :)